# How to retrieve element by key after using instaparse in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I am trying to make a compiler for a school project. I am a beginner in clojure. I have done a simple program (*interpreting-lang-if*) which can parse a string using instaparse and return a vector like this :

```
[:LangIF [:before_if "676767; "] [:condition_expression "0"] 
[:statements_OK "1; 2;"] [:statements_NOK "3+4;"] [:after_if ""]]
```

How can I get the "before_if" element from the list?

I tried to understand the get function but I must have minsunderstood something in the usage of the function.

Here is some code :

```
(prn (interpreting-lang-if "676767; if (0) {1; 2;}else{3+4;};"))
(get (interpreting-lang-if "676767; if (0) {1; 2;}else{3+4;};") :before_if)
(get :before_if (interpreting-lang-if "676767; if (0) {1; 2;}else{3+4;};"))
```

The expected output is supposed to be *"676767"* instead of *nil*.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont know the exact position of the item:

```
(->> [:LangIF [:before_if "676767; "] [:condition_expression "0"]
      [:statements_OK "1; 2;"] [:statements_NOK "3+4;"] [:after_if ""]]
     (tree-seq vector? rest)
     (filter vector?)
     (filter (comp (partial = :before_if) first))
     (first)
     (second))
```

or if you do and would like to use specter:

```
(let [A [:LangIF [:before_if "676767; "] [:condition_expression "0"]
       [:statements_OK "1; 2;"] [:statements_NOK "3+4;"] [:after_if ""]]]
    (select [1 1] A))
```

or with simple get:

```
(let [A [:LangIF [:before_if "676767; "] [:condition_expression "0"]
       [:statements_OK "1; 2;"] [:statements_NOK "3+4;"] [:after_if ""]]]
    (get (get A 1) 1))
```

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I was looking for ! The first one is more relevant for my project and its evolution.  The simple get is also working in my case. Your code is very inspiring.

Comment: Or, for the `get`, there's also `(get-in A [1 1])`.

Answer (score 1):

I've found zippers to be useful with Instaparse ASTs, especially when you need to find a particular node then find another node relative to it. Here's a function that searches through nodes to find the one matching a predicate:

```
(require '[clojure.zip :as zip])

(defn zip-to
  ([loc pred direction]
   (loop [loc loc]
     (if (and loc (not (zip/end? loc)))
       (if (pred (zip/node loc))
         loc
         (recur (direction loc)))
       loc))))
```

To find `:before_if` in your AST:

```
(-> [:LangIF
     [:before_if "676767; "]
     [:condition_expression "0"]
     [:statements_OK "1; 2;"]
     [:statements_NOK "3+4;"]
     [:after_if ""]]
  zip/vector-zip
  (zip-to #{:before_if} zip/next)
  zip/right
  zip/node)
```

Comment: Thanks I have tried it. It is a useful advice. I will keep it in mind

Answer (score 1):

You can easily manipulate tree-like data-structures using the Tupelo Forest library.  Here is [a live example of your problem](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/test/clj/tst/tupelo/forest_examples.clj#L1521):

```
(dotest
  (with-forest (new-forest)
    (let [data-hiccup  [:LangIF
                        [:before_if "676767; "]
                        [:condition_expression "0"]
                        [:statements_OK "1; 2;"]
                        [:statements_NOK "3+4;"]
                        [:after_if ""]]

          root-hid     (add-tree-hiccup data-hiccup)
          before-hid   (find-hid root-hid [:LangIF :before_if])
          before-node  (hid->node before-hid)
          before-value (grab :value before-node)]

      (is= before-node {:tupelo.forest/khids [], :tag :before_if, :value "676767; "})
      (is= before-value "676767; "))))
```

`before-hid` is a pointer to the desired node, which we find by specifying the desired path `[:LangIF :before_if]` from the root node. We can then convert the pointer into the entire node, and extract the `:value` from the node. Many further manipulations are possible.  See [the docs](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/docs/forest.adoc) and [more examples](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/test/clj/tst/tupelo/forest_examples.clj).